# Cordova: command not found after installing globally

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm, ionic4

I try to install Cordova in macOS Mojave. I run the following command to install globally. It is installed successfully `npm i -g cordova`

but when I check the version using `cordova --version` , It gives me the error "cordova: command not found".

and also when I try to get the location using `which cordova`, It returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this great write up: http://blog.webbb.be/command-not-found-node-npm/

This can happen when npm is installing to a location that is not the standard and is not in your path.

> To check where npm is installing, run: `npm root -g`

It SHOULD say `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, If it doesn't then follow this:

**Set it to the correct PATH:**

- run: `npm config set prefix /usr/local`
- Then reinstall your npm package(s) with -g: 
  `npm install -g cordova` etc

If this doesn't work then try adding the global path of cordova(where it got installed) to your **`$PATH`** variable.